# Real Analysis: Cauchy-Schwarz inequality proof

Tags: real-analysis

Appearing in Tao's Analysis II, this proof contains some series manipulations.

($\sum_{i=1}^n a_{i}b_{i}$)$^2$ + $\frac{1}{2}$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n (a_{i}b_{j}-a_{j}b_{i}$)$^2$ = $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^{2}) (\sum_{j=1}^n b_j^{2})$

Induction base case holds.

for $n=k-1$ case there's a sum of two double series, the second double series:

$\frac{1}{2}$$\sum_{i=1}^k (\sum_{j=1}^{k-1} (a_{i}b_{j}-a_{j}b_{i}$)$^2$ + $(a_{i}b_{k}-a_{k}b_{i}$)$^2$)

is broken down into

$\frac{1}{2}$$\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} (a_{i}b_{j}-a_{j}b_{i}$)$^2$ +

$\frac{1}{2}$$ \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (a_{i}b_{k}-a_{k}b_{i}$)$^2$ +

$\frac{1}{2}$$ \sum_{j=1}^{k-1} (a_{k}b_{j}-a_{j}b_{k}$)$^2$

I don't know why the last term has the k subscript where the i subscript was when the summation is from j=1 to k-1. In other words I don't understand why the breakdown happens this way with regards to the modified upper limit $k-1$.

Additionally, the last two terms collectively will equal a single sum

$ \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (a_{i}b_{k}-a_{k}b_{i}$)$^2$

Additionally, that then absorbs $2a_kb_k \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} a_{i}b_{i}$ and is simplified into

$ \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} [(a_{i}b_{k})^2 + (a_{k}b_{i}$)$^2]$

Can someone help me make sense of these manipulations?

Comment: "I don't know why the last term has the k subscript where the i subscript was when the summation is from j=1 to k-1." That's because $(a_kb_k-a_kb_k)^2=0$.

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown, I see it thank you